# MySQL select * with distinct id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a row with a distinct id, yet return all the fields.

```
SELECT * DISTINCT(ID) FROM table WHERE ...
```

I ultimately need the ID, City, State and Zip.  How can I get rows that are not duplicate ID's and return all fields into my mysql_fetch_array?

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * DISTINCT(ID) FROM table WHERE ...

SELECT DISTINCT ID * FROM table WHERE ...

SELECT ID,City,State,Zip DISTINCT ID FROM ...

SELECT ID,City,State,Zip DISTINCT(ID) FROM ...
```

I was reading other questions here and none seem to help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `DISTINCT` will simply return unique IDs from the table; what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I need more than just the IDs... thanks though

Comment: So with same id, which record should be selected?

Comment: if there are multiple records of same `ID` having different addresses... which address would you then want? random?

Comment: I wanted to select 4 rows with different ID's which I would use the City, State and Zip.  I needed to make sure that duplicate ID's were ignored because I am sorting the data returned.  As far as ID's that have different addresses, it shouldn't matter which address to show, I just don't want duplicates.  Thanks for your help, problem averted.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
  select id, city, state, zip
    from mytable
group by id
```

Note that this will return an arbitrary address for each `id` if there are duplicates.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0eba/1

Comment: would I add the group by before or after the WHERE?

Comment: @NotJay - group by goes after the where

Comment: @NotJay: Let me just point out that this is an atypical use of `GROUP BY`.  The main purpose is for aggregation, that is to find MIN, MAX, SUM or other summary value per group.  For instance, you might use `GROUP BY` to combine results of sales data by month to generate monthly totals and averages.  I'm exploiting the fact that `mysql` allows you to refer to columns not being grouped in a query, which is undefined behavior (disallowed) in most other database systems.  Cheers!

Comment: @mellamokb: good point, you should add it to the answer, rather than leaving it in a comment!

Comment: it always returns me all the fields, using the same query ... any idea how to do this?